# Facebook Chatbot Persistent Menu doesn't work (parameter setting_type is required)

Tags: facebook, curl, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I'm currently trying to implement a Persistent Menu for my Facebook Chatbot. Sadly there are two (completely different) documentation for the implementation which both don't work for me. (Both should work for API v2.6)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-profile/persistent-menu
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/persistent-menu

I used this simple call which is returning an error **(#100) The parameter setting_type is required**

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "persistent_menu":[
    {
    "call_to_actions":[
        {
          "type":"web_url",
          "title":"Einstellungen",
          "url":"https://{{url-part}}.cloudfront.net/",
          "webview_height_ratio":"full"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "locale":"de_DE",
      "composer_input_disabled":false
    }
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token={{token}}"
```

If I use the second documentation with `"setting_type" : "call_to_actions"` the same error occurs.
Why I can't set up a Persistent Menu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below works for me.

Make sure you are sending the request to the new endpoint, `messenger_profile`. You have to provide at least a default locale.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "persistent_menu":[
    {
    "locale":"default",
    "composer_input_disabled":false,
    "call_to_actions":[
        {
          "type":"web_url",
          "title":"Einstellungen",
          "url":"https://{{url-part}}.cloudfront.net",
          "webview_height_ratio":"full"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token={{token}}"
```

Comment: hii @john can you help this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53978285/uploading-mp4-video-using-curl-to-facebook  ?